# Javascript: How to get caret offset from start of content editable div with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, dom, getselection

I having a problem getting the caret position from the start of a content editable div using Javascript. I am able to get the offset from the --beginning of the line-- but not from the beginning of the div. The offset from the beginning of the div is what I want. For example:

```
This is line number one.
This []is line number two.  <-- [] Denotes where the caret position is
```

When trying to find the caret position from the --beginning of the div-- I am getting the value 6 when I really want 30.
Here is the code I am using:

```
function updateCursorPosition() {
            cursorPosition = window.getSelection().baseOffset;
            alert(cursorPosition);
        }
```

This function is fired with an onclick event. As stated before, I am only getting the offset  from the beginning of the line and not the beginning of the div. Thank anyone in advanced for your input.

The offset I am looking for is in **characters**, not in pixels.

Comment: It's not an easy thing to do by yourself, your only hope is to somehow find something on the internet, but since the internet is a black hole, it's gonna be hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the function below:

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ThVr/

```
var getCaretPixelPos = function ($node, offsetx, offsety){
    offsetx = offsetx || 0;
    offsety = offsety || 0;

    var nodeLeft = 0,
        nodeTop = 0;
    if ($node){
        nodeLeft = $node.offsetLeft;
        nodeTop = $node.offsetTop;
    }

    var pos = {left: 0, top: 0};

    if (document.selection){
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        pos.left = range.offsetLeft + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
        pos.top = range.offsetTop + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
    }else if (window.getSelection){
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        try{
            range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset-1);
        }catch(e){}
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (range.endOffset == 0 || range.toString() === ''){
            // first char of line
            if (range.startContainer == $node){
                // empty div
                if (range.endOffset == 0){
                    pos.top = '0px';
                    pos.left = '0px';
                }else{
                    // firefox need this
                    var range2 = range.cloneRange();
                    range2.setStart(range2.startContainer, 0);
                    var rect2 = range2.getBoundingClientRect();
                    pos.left = rect2.left + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
                    pos.top = rect2.top + rect2.height + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
                }
            }else{
                pos.top = range.startContainer.offsetTop+'px';
                pos.left = range.startContainer.offsetLeft+'px';
            }
        }else{
            pos.left = rect.left + rect.width + offsetx - nodeLeft + 'px';
            pos.top = rect.top + offsety - nodeTop + 'px';
        }
    }
    return pos;
};
```

the following function might help. It will give you the start and end selected characters from the beginning of the textarea. If there is no selection, it will give you the char position of the caret:

```
function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}
```

use example:

```
var selection = getInputSelection(textarea);
var start = selection.start;
var end = selection.end;
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob for your hasty reply. I updated my question noting that I am looking for a character offset and not a pixel offset.

Comment: @Korupshen updated my answer with another function that might be helpful for what you're trying to do :)